# Is it possible to use Traefik if you have a DNS provider not on their list?

Tags: docker, ssl, https, traefik

I really like the idea of Traefik, and it's easy to set up and use, but the problem I've had is getting SSL/TLS to work with it. Traefik has a list of approved DNS providers [here](https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/), but I use Dynu.com, which isn't on the list.

Is there a way to use HTTPS with Traefik since I'm using Dynu.com and not one of their approved providers? I don't want to pay for another provider since I've already paid for Dynu, which has served me fine. CloudFlare is out as it's only for personal use, which is not what I'm doing. I've tried DuckDNS but got lost in their instructions since they only support .duckdns.org addresses.

Is there any way to make Traefik work with Dynu? I'm not that familiar with HTTPS so I'd need some instructions.

Answer (score -1):

The DNS providers listed in the documentation is for the DNS challenge.

To get a Let's Encrypt(acme) certificates, you can use several challenges: TLS Challenge or HTTP challenge or DNS challenge.

The DNS challenge is the only challenge that support wildcard certificates (ex: `*.foo.com`).

If you don't need wildcard certificates, you can use the other challenges (like TLS challenge, it's the simplest challenge to configure.)

The challenges are automatically resolved by Traefik.

- https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/https/acme/#tlschallenge
- https://letsencrypt.org/docs/